# Get distinct dates in datatable

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

In the datatable,  column contains values:

```
Column1
-------
2013-03-26 11:40:24.623
2013-03-26 11:20:24.623
2013-03-26 11:00:24.623
2013-03-26 10:40:24.623
2013-03-26 10:20:24.623
2013-03-26 10:10:24.623
...
```

I need to get list containing distinct date parts.

I tried:

```
List<DateTime> dateList = (
    from row in dt.AsEnumerable() 
    select row.Field<DateTime>("TimeStamp").Date
).Distinct().ToList<DateTime>();
```

It treats each value as distinct. How to avoid time part?

Comment: **distinct date parts?** Can you explain it.

Comment: Sorry, I meant distinct dates like: 03/24/2013, 03/25/2013, ...

Comment: This works: dataTable.AsEnumerable().Select(row => row.Field<DateTime>("TimeStamp").Date).Distinct().ToList<DateTime>();

Comment: Your code should work fine, it would return a single item in the list for your current data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Enumerable.Distinct](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.distinct.aspx)

```
dt.AsEnumerable().Distinct(r => row.Field<DateTime>("TimeStamp").Date);
```